# how to set this type of bottom border textfield?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to set only bottom border textfield ? what kind of coding i have used...

I want this type of output screen

[image: I want this type of output screen]

This is my coding

```
border = [CALayer layer];
    CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
    border.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, firstname.frame.size.height - borderWidth, firstname.frame.size.width, firstname.frame.size.height);
    border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    [firstname.layer addSublayer:border];
    firstname.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: If you want to do this without using UITableView , please check my answer... @user1205

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this without using `UITableView` ,

Try following code:

```
CALayer *yourborder = [CALayer layer];
CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
yourborder.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
yourborder.frame = CGRectMake(0, firstname.frame.size.height - borderWidth, firstname.frame.size.width, firstname.frame.size.height);
yourborder.borderWidth = borderWidth;
[firstname.layer addSublayer:yourborder];
firstname.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: yeah i tried ...this code also work thank you @suraj

Answer (score 0):

Use `UITableView` for this kind of form and for bottom border use line separator of `tableview` and use below type of `textFiled` for your desire output.

```
txtName.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: this code hide only top border ...doesn't hide left and right border

Comment: Thats why what i mention you in my answer that use tableview to design your UI its very easy to get this type of design in table view with Normal textfiled into cell.

Answer (score 0):

Create extension on UIView

```
     //extension
     extension UIView {

          func bottomBorder(color color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
                let border = CALayer()
                border.backgroundColor = color.CGColor
                border.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - width, self.frame.size.width, width)
                border.masksToBounds = true
                self.layer.addSublayer(border)
           }
    }
```

call this method like

```
firstname.bottomBorder(color: UIColor.whiteColor(), width: 2)
```

for the effect you are trying you can use UITableview alternatively